# Passing Json collection to MVC3 controller

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to send a json "collection" to an MVC3 controller.  I've done this fairly easily before when the incoming object is an array, **but in this instance there's no array (unless nested {} is an 'array'?)**.

I've tried various model configurations, as well, such as: `FormCollection`, `Dictionary<string, FooBar[]>`, and some others, but it's always null.

What am I doing wrong that's causing the fancy json-binder-thing to not work?

Thanks.

**Building the JSON object**

```
function getJson() {
    var foobars = {};

    foobars["FooBar1"] = { "Foo": "baz1", "Bar": 1 };
    foobars["FooBar2"] = { "Foo": "baz2", "Bar": 2 };
}
```

**getJson() yields this Json object**

```
{
    "FooBar1" : 
    {
        "Foo":"baz1", 
        "Bar":1
    },
    "FooBar2" : 
    {
        "Foo":"baz2", 
        "Bar":2
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class FooBarModel
{
    public FooBar[] FooBars { get; set; }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void ParseFooBars(FooBarModel model)
{
    //model is null
}
```

**jQuery ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MyController/ParseFooBars",
    data: JSON.stringify(getJson()),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "Bar" in json and "Baz" in model, is it a typo?
If not, this could be a reason of failed mapping.

Another reason will be default model binding, it works correctly with IEnumerable<> but I'm not sure that it either works with arrays. You may want to try custom model binder for your FooBarModel.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo.  I feel as though I'm not being clear or I'm ignorant about some aspect of Json because you're mentioning "array" but I don't have any array notation in my Json.  It's purely `{"SomeParentKey" : { "Key" : value } }`

Answer (score 0):

First question - are you sure you're hitting the right controller? Stepping through using debugger will confirm this. I've been bitten in the behind many times by not noticing that.

Secondly, it would appear you're sending a dictionary and not an array. In your JSON you have a collection of named instances but in your controller you're expecting an array of unnamed instances. If you changed your JSON to look like this does it work?:

```
function getJson() {
    var foobars = [];

    foobars.push({ "Foo": "baz1", "Bar": 1 });
    foobars.push({ "Foo": "baz2", "Bar": 2 });
    return foobars;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is the correct controller. Secondly, as stated in the question, I have tried various other types for the model -- none of which have properly bound to the incoming Json.  Thirdly, again as I mentioned in the question, I have done this a lot in the past using arrays without issue, but in this instance I have no arrays.  Additionally, your proposed solution doesn't generate the same Json as it's missing the parent "FooBar1" key.

Comment: To your second point, yes I was aware that you had tried various types. My point was, if the model binder is indeed trying to bind to a dictionary there are specific ways to do that. Of course arrays can be bound, but as mentioned, the issue is the model binder and the json. Can you not modify the json that's being sent? You can always write your own model binder but modifying the json would be easier. Using the script above and changing the action to accept `FooBar[] model` results in the correct binding. If you cannot modify the json, you may be left with writing your own model binder.

Comment: For binding to a dictionary [see here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Comment: Oh, definitely.  I can "make it work" by changing things around, but this seems so trivial that it "should work," ya know? I can't imagine I'm the first person that wanted to bind regular Json.  I've done some reading and it appears that, as I feared, the default binding behavior simply doesn't support this type of input.  I was hoping someone would know some magical solution, though.  I appreciate your help.  I'm just going a bit crazy at the moment.

Comment: Completely understandable! Indeed it would seem like it would be a relatively common use case.